# How does Spring Security OAuth2 know when a token expires?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I added a JDBC token store and added the SQL from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql (except the 1st and last tables). Then I fetched a token:

```
$ curl -u xxx:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials -d client_id=xxx -d client_secret=123456 -d scope=write

{"access_token":"0cbd0733-2c37-400b-abd7-5d1507c2204f","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":42498,"scope":"write"}
```

The only table with a timestamp is `oauth_approvals` but it's empty!

```
MariaDB [xxxxxx]> select * from oauth_approvals;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So how does Spring know when a token expires?

I restarted the server and verified the token still works and was the same token.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oauth with JWT (json web token) then check this article: https://jwt.io/introduction/

JSON Web Tokens consist of three parts separated by dots (.), which are:
    Header
    Payload
    Signature
Therefore, a JWT typically looks like the following.
xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

The payload contains claims which represent information about an entity and the token itself. Among those claims is: iss (issuer), exp (expiration time), sub (subject), aud (audience).

So basically the expiration time is in the token and can be verified using the token itself.

The payload may not contain an exp claim => the token does not expire.

Comment: No I am not using JWT tokens. https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#managing-tokens

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but here it goes.

You are actually using the `client_credentials` grant type which means you are not authorizing your client application on behalf of a `Resource owner` but instead you are accessing your own account (without any username/password). Therefore the `oauth_approvals` will not be populated. In fact this table is only used for the `authorization_code` grant type when a `Resource owner` "authorize" the Client to access his account on his behalf.

Based on your question the tables that should have been populated are:

- `oauth_access_token`: Which principal and clientId are using what
  access_token. In this table the token column stores all the
  information including the expiration time that you were asking for.
- `oauth_refresh_token`: The refresh token to request a new access
  token after it will expired.

This table `oauth_client_details` holds the client information. You stated that you are not using it so I assume you are storing in-memory the Client details.

Read more about the oAuth2 protocol here: https://oauth.net/2/